# Get the maximum sum for a file on 2 keys

Tags: awk, perl

I have a file as below.

```
key1 key2  key3
a1    2    l1
a1    2.5  l2
a2    2    l2
a3    2.5  l3
a3    2.1  l4
a3    2.2  l5
```

I am trying to find the maximum possible sum of `key2` that satisfies the condition that `key1` and `key3` occur only once. For the above file, I expect the output as,

```
a1 2     l1
a2 2     l2
a3 2.5   l3
```

If I use the below command,

```
sort -nk2 file | perl -ane '$k{$F[$1]}=$_; END{print "$k{$_}" for keys(%k)}'
```

I get the output as,

```
a2 2   l2
a1 2.5 l2
a3 2.5 l3
```

However, I wish to get only one occurrence of `key1` and `key3` in the output as well as getting the maximum sum as I have described in the expected output.

**EDIT**

I have the input file as below.

```
a0 11.1    l6
a0 3       l1
a1 14.0    l6
a1 2.5     l2
a2 11.1    l2
a2 2       l2
a3 13.3    l8
a3 2.1     l4
a3 2.5     l7
a4 1.6     l6
a4 1.7     l1
```

As we can manually see, the maximum weighted output for the above file would be,

```
a0 11.1 l6
a2 11.1  l2
a3 13.3 l8
a4 1.7  l1
```

As per Gnouc's `awk` command, I get the output as,

```
a0 11.1  l6
a1 2.5   l2
a3 13.3  l8
a4 1.7   l1
```

As per terdon's `perl` command, I get the output as,

```
a2 2   l2
a4 1.7 l1
a3 13.3 l8
```

**EDIT 3**

```
a1 1 l1
a2 3 l2
a1 4 l3
a3 5 l2
a6 4 l5
a7 3 l2
```

I get the output as,

```
a3 5 l2
a6 4 l5
a7 3 l2
```

As we can see, `l2` is repeated twice.

Comment: what do you mean by "maximum sum"? Are you adding values in the key2 column together if column 1 and column 3 have the same value?

Comment: Why `a1 2.5   l2` does not contain in output when it occurs first compare with `a2 11.1  l2`?

Comment: @Gnouc, I am trying to find the maximum sum possible for the `key2` column. So, as per the output that I have showed, we are getting the maximum sum as 37.2. But, when I use awk command as you suggested, the maximum sum I get is 28.6.

Comment: @Ramesh: If that, I think the line `a0 11.1 l6` should not appear. The line `a1 14.0    l6` will make the sum of key2 bigger.

Comment: @Gnouc, sorry my bad. You are right. `a1` should be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you only want to get the first occurence of each `key1`.

This will procduce your expected output:

```
$ awk '!($1 in a){print;a[$1]}' file
a1    2    l1
a2    2    l2
a3    2.5  l3
```

**Update**

If you want `key1` **or** `key3` should occur only once:

```
$ awk '!($1 in a) && !($3 in a){print;a[$1];a[$3]}' 1.txt 
a1    2    l1
a2    2    l2
a3    2.5  l3
```

**Update 2**

After reading your comment, I think here is the solution:

```
$ sort -rnk2 file | awk '!a[$1]++' | awk '!a[$3]++'
a1 14.0    l6
a3 13.3    l8
a2 11.1    l2
a4 1.7     l1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, if I have one more value in my input file as, `a0 2.5 l1` I should not have `a1` occurrence. However, when I run the `awk` command, I still get both `a0` and `a1`.

Comment: @Ramesh: you mean you want key3 unique?

Comment: the combination of `key1` and `key3` will act as unique. So, I am trying to find the maximum sum of the file (which is for `column2`), and also at the same time satisfying the above condition. That is, `key1` or `key3` should occur only once. If it is not contributing to the maximum sum, then I do not need them.

Comment: @Ramesh: See my updated answer!

Comment: @Ramesh: Did you try it?

Comment: Thanks for the updated command. I have updated the question with the command's output and the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, about the edit rollback, was too quick.

Comment: @Gnouc, if I use the input file as specified in edit3 of my question, the output seems not correct. Please see the edit3 of my question. I am afraid I have to use a recursive solution to achieve what am looking for. :(

Comment: @Ramesh: Sorry, my mistypo. Fixed it! You can try it.

Comment: @Gnouc, thanks. This one seems to work without any break for the inputs I tried so far. I will accept the answer. But if I have some more questions, I will link this question and post it as a new question. Thanks for your time. I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @Ramesh: You're welcome. Don't mind to ask any question.

Answer (score 3):

You could just add a test to your perl script. Use another hash whose keys are the 3rd field and print each line only if that field has not yet been seen:

```
$ sort -nk2 file | perl -ane '$k{$F[$1]}=$_ unless $s{$F[2]}++>0; 
                              END{print "$k{$_}" for keys(%k)}'
a3    2.5  l3
a2    2    l2
a1    2    l1
```

NOTE: This will print the header as well but so will your approach and since you're not showing it in your output, I am assuming that the header is not actually part of the file.

Comment: thanks for suggesting me a perl solution. Please see my updates to the question.